# How to fix error and split mined Tweets into words?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Currently working on a visualization for Tweets from Twitter
Would be very grateful if someone could help me out :)

Code to pull Tweets from Twitter:

```
tweets2 =tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search_term).items(tweet_amount)
for tweet in tweets2:
    print(tweet)
```

#Now I want to add the mined Tweets and split them into words

```
all_sentences = []

for word in tweet:       
    all_sentences.append(word)
    print(all_sentences)

lines = list()
for line in all_sentences:
    words = line.split()
    for w in words:
        lines.append(w)

print(lines)
```

Thereby I am getting an error:

```
in <module>
    for word in tweet:
TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know how to conquer this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `Status`/[Tweet objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) themselves are not iterable.
To get the text of the Tweet, you can use its `text` attribute.

Comment: How do i do that in specicfic?

Comment: `tweet.text` would be the string with the text of the Tweet.